# Is it possible to create an EMF package from java code at runtime?

Tags: java, eclipse-emf

I want to create EMF models from java code at runtime. The generative approach doesn't suit my needs because every time the java classes change, I'm forced to update my model. I want a model that exactly corresponds to my java code, so I can convert EMF objects to java objects and vice versa. I googled my problem and found MoDisco that does the job but it is doing it at design time.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible and is done by EMF behind the scene all the time. Have a look at the generated `...Package.java` for an example.

Also see [EMF generate model class from ECore XMI at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13778741/796559) and http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1323360&seqNum=5

Comment: The problem is we refused to adopt the model driven approach for maintainability reasons and we are not interested in "generating" java code from EMF model. We have some java entity classes and we need some framework to create EMF classes from them at application startup, not at design time.